# How TCP Client(golang) knows when data end if TCP Server(nodejs) send data without separator "\n"

Tags: node.js, go, tcp

**My problem:**

I'm trying to read the data sended by TCP server(nodejs)
but I can't, the server send the data without breakline "\r\n" or "\n"

I'm new in Golang but I have been trying a lot of things to get all the data sended by server.

**Code from Server.js, this a simple example**

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    console.log("New Client")

    socket.on('data', function(data){
        console.log("data",data,data.toString())
        socket.write("qweqweqkjwebqkjwhbekqjwbekjqbwkejhqwkjehqkwjehkqjwehkqjwhekjqhwekjhqwe")
    })
    socket.on('error', function(error){
        console.error("Error:",error)
    })
});

server.listen(4001, '127.0.0.1');
```

**My code from golang**

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:4001")

    for {
        fmt.Println("Send Text")
        fmt.Fprintf(conn, "Hello")

        // message, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
        // message, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\r')
        message, _, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadLine() // how i know when data end if server doesn't send separator like "\n" "\r"
        fmt.Println("Message from server: " + message)

        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
    }
}
```

**Output from Client Golang:**

```
Send Text
```

And that is all, the client(golang) is waiting for new line

**Questions**:

1.- There is a standard size of buffer in net(nodejs) ?
2.- How I can read the data sended by Server in golang without breakline? (there is no problem client and server in nodejs)
3.- I need to read byte by byte? and find \x00 from buffer sended by Server(nodejs) ? (if this is the case how?)
4.- Server and Client in nodejs works with separator, but when they send data to the other one, in the other side separator is deleted?

**I have teste this examples, but no one `break` the cicle `for`**

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    // for {
    //  time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
    //  // buff := make([]byte, 4)
    //  test, _ := reader.ReadByte()
    //  fmt.Printf("%q\n", test)
    //  fmt.Printf("%x\n", test)
    // }

    // buf := make([]byte, 1)
    // for {
    //  n, err := reader.Read(buf)
    //  fmt.Println(n, err, buf[:n])
    //  if err == io.EOF {
    //      break
    //  }
    // }

    // buf := make([]byte, 4)
    // if _, err := io.ReadFull(reader, buf); err != nil {
    //  log.Fatal(err)
    // }
    // fmt.Println(string(buf))

    buf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(buf))
```

Comment: then how does your golang server understands the command is finished ?! its like asking a way to issue a command in terminal without pressing Enter. I think what you want is a websocket like protocol

Comment: @danicheeta then how Client and Server TCP in nodejs works?,  If I execute `socket.write(data)` without separator("\n") in the server(js), data go to on `socket.on('data', function)` in client side, and  my questions is how can I emulate this with golang?

Comment: it must append `\n`  under the hood. I havent checked that out but its logical to me

Answer (score 0):

It's about TCP data transfer, usually in this case you should define a protocol for your data to define how much byte will be send and usually a separator for end of packet. for example

```
[n-Bytes for data lenght][data][separator bytes]
```

In fact, `ReadLine` also uses this method but only with separator

Comment: but how a server and client TCP in nodejs know when data ends if there isn't a "separator byte" in the data that I send?